How to acces the attributes of an Object other in the equals method?
I am trying to overwrite the equals method with this code:
public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(!(other instanceof Termino)) return false;
        if(this.hashValue == other.hashValue) return true;
        return false;
}

As far as I know, instanceof returns true if other is an object of the class Termino, so other would have an attribute named hashValue, but I got the error valorHash cannot be resolved or is not a field. Why?
My solution, that worked, is this:
public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(!(other instanceof Termino)) return false;
        Termino aux = (Termino) other;
        if(this.hashValue == aux.hashValue) return true;
        return false;
}

But I do not understand why my first attempt is wrong.

If you try to access an object's attribute using the first method, it won't work because it would look for hashValue on the 'Object' class. When you cast it, you allow it to access the attributes of the Termino class.

The Java equals method is part of the Object class. It is not generic, so you will have to take care of casting the thing you are comparing to an object of the same type as the class that is overriding it.
Make sure that you can use == on the field. If it is a primitive that is fine, but if it's an object, you will have to call equals on it.
A standard equals method will look like this:
import java.util.Objects;

public class Termino {
    private String hashValue;

    public Termino(String hashValue) {
        this.hashValue = hashValue;
    }

    public String getHashValue() {
        return hashValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        Termino termino = (Termino) obj;
        return Objects.equals(hashValue, termino.hashValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(hashValue);
    }
}

If you are using Java 14 or higher, you can use the instanceof pattern matching for auto-casting:
import java.util.Objects;

public class Termino {
    private String hashValue;

    public Termino(String hashValue) {
        this.hashValue = hashValue;
    }

    public String getHashValue() {
        return hashValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Termino termino)) return false;
        return Objects.equals(hashValue, termino.hashValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(hashValue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Termino a1 = new Termino("a");
        Termino a2 = new Termino("a");

        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2)); // true
    }
}

If you are using Java 16 or higher, you can use a record and skip the hash code method all together.
public record Termino(String hashValue) {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Termino a1 = new Termino("a");
        Termino a2 = new Termino("a");

        System.out.println(a1.equals(a2)); // true
    }
}


As a statically typed language, Java uses the compile-time type of a value for determining whether a method or field belongs to a given object.  Since other is declared to be of type Object, and Object does not have a hashValue field, the compiler does not know that other has a hashValue field.  It is therefore a compilation error to attempt to access the hashValue field on other.
public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(!(other instanceof Termino)) return false;
        if(this.hashValue == other.hashValue) return true;
        return false;
}

Your second solution works because aux is of type Termino, which does have a hashValue field.  The compiler knows it's working with a Termino and knows how to retrieve the value of hashValue from it.
public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(!(other instanceof Termino)) return false;
        Termino aux = (Termino) other;
        if(this.hashValue == aux.hashValue) return true;
        return false;
}

